# How do you access related entries co-located with data affinity in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to use Hazelcast's map-reduce feature to perform an aggregate operation, which needs to access the co-located entries.  The co-location is controlled using [data-affinity](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/manual/html/ch06.html).

Imagine the classic *customer*/*order* model as used in the [Hazelcast documentation on data-affinity](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/manual/html/ch06.html).  In my example I want to return a *customer summary* that has the *customer* and the sum of all their orders, for example, given this data set:

```
customer_id | name
------------------
1           | Dave
2           | Kate


order_id | customer_id | value
------------------------------
1        | 1           | 5
2        | 1           | 10
3        | 2           | 12
```

I want to return:

```
customer_id | name | value
--------------------------
1           | Dave | 15
2           | Kate | 12
```

This is simple enough, however the reason for using data-affinity is to be able to perform the summing logic within the respective partition holding the data by simply getting all the orders within that partition and therefore avoiding any cross JVM communication.

And so my question, from within a [Mapper](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/mapreduce/Mapper.html) or similar, how do you get the co-located entries in another cache?

**EDIT:**

After @noctarius' answer and comments, here's some code (I've tried to make it as brief as possible) that highlights the point at which I only want the orders from the current partition.

The order key class looks like this:

```
public class OrderKey implements PartitionAware<CustomerIdentity>
{
  ...

  @Override
  public CustomerIdentity getPartitionKey()
  {
    return this.customerIdentity; 
  }

  ...
}
```

And the `Mapper` like this:

```
public class OrderSumMapper implements Mapper<CustomerKey, Customer, CustomerKey, CustomerOrderTotal>, HazelcastInstanceAware
{
  ...

  @Override
  public void map(CustomerKey customerKey, Customer customer, Context<CustomerKey, CustomerOrderTotal> context)
  {
    Predicate ordersForCustomer = new OrdersForCustomerPredicate(customerKey);

    int totalValue = 0;

    //******************************************************************
    //
    // Given orders are co-located with the customer, how do you ensure 
    // this call to get the orders only runs in the current partition?
    //
    //******************************************************************

    for (Order order : hazelcastInstance.getMap("orders").values(ordersForCustomer))
    {
      totalValue += order.getValue();
    }

    context.emit(customerKey, new CustomerOrderTotal(customer, total));
  }

  ...
}
```

The highlighted call `hazelcastInstance.getMap("orders").values(ordersForCustomer)` would ordinarily hit all nodes in the cluster, but because the data is co-located this is an unncessary overhead.

And so back to me original question, how you I get the orders such that only those in the current partition are returned?

Comment: For those familiar with Coherence, you would acheive this with an Aggregator and get the co-located entries via the backing-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out, which will hopefully this prove useful to others (and so I'm shamelessly answering and accepting my own question).

After some experimentation it is possible to get to the objects held in another map within the partition from a `Mapper` running in that partition.

The first thing is to have the `Mapper` implement `NodeAware`, which causes Hazelcast to inject a reference to the `Node` the `Mapper` is running in.

Once you have the `Node`, you can write a method like this to access data in other maps within a given partition like this:

```
private Collection<Order> getCustomerOrders(CustomerKey customerKey)
{
  List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

  MapService mapService = node.getClusterService().getNodeEngine().getService(MapService.SERVICE_NAME);

  RecordStore recordStore = mapService.getRecordStore(node.getPartitionService().getPartitionId(customerKey), "orders");

  for (Data key : recordStore.keySet())
  {
    OrderKey orderKey = mapService.getSerializationService().toObject(key);

    if (customerKey.equals(orderKey.getCustomerKey()))
    {
      orders.add(mapService.getSerializationService().toObject(recordStore.get(key)));
    }
  }

  return orders;
}
```

There's a bit of a deserialization overhead, but that'd be the case using a `Predicate` and working this way keeps all the processing performed by the `Mapper` in the JVM containing the data being mapped therefore avoiding any expensive process/network hops - basically it 'should' be faster and will definately cut down on the network traffic caused by inter-node communication.

Comment: Looking at ways to minimize the deserialization overhead, I notice you can get a `PortableReader` from the `SerializationService`, which would allow the `CustomerKey` to be plucked out of the serialized `OrderKey` without deserializing everything

Comment: As far as I know NodeAware is 3.3+ so probably this will not work on 3.2 and you use private API which always is subject of changes. We do not yet expose those things to users SPI but you're right, we eventually need to do that to make it convenient to use. Can you please fill out an enhancement request on github?

Answer (score 0):

You just inject the current node's HazelcastInstance into your Mapper and retrieve the second data structure to read the data.

See a basic example here:
https://github.com/noctarius/hazelcast-mapreduce-presentation/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/examples/tutorials/impl/SalaryMapper.java

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - is your code is working because you use the same key for both `Person` and `SalaryYear`?  How would you access the `SalaryYear`s if multiple years were being stored, keyed with a composite key of `email` and `year`?

Comment: Why should it have something to do with the key? You can use any key you want to retrieve another value from another map. Those are independent data structures. If you're asking because consistent partition snapshots that is not yet implemented but will be soon. In this case you'll have a consistent view over all data structures in the same partition at a given time.

Comment: The key is important because your mapping is running against the cache containing the master values - customers in my case, people in yours.  This means that, in my case, where I want to retrieve all orders for the customers in a given partition, I don't have the complete key, only the customer id.  I think you would have the same problem if you were to have multiple years for each person.  I'm wondering if this can be achieved with a `PartitionAware` `Predicate` - do you know if that works?

Comment: I still don't got your problem, why not simply use a MultiMap for the orders and just retrieve that inside the Mapper? I guess I don't understand your problem, so probably add some demo code.

Comment: A `MultiMap` would only satisfy a single use-case however what I want is a map of orders keyed by their composite identity (customer and order id).  I then want to map-reduce against customers and have the `Mapper` access only the orders in a given partition, which are co-located with the customers.  I'll add some code and to highlight the point at which I want only the orders in a given partition

Comment: Ahh ok I see the problem. That's actually a good question. Looking forward to some example code, I'm pretty sure we can find a solution to this :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a subtle one.  I've used Coherence pretty heavily and this is one of the big performance gains you get from using a distributed cache - you push the processing to the data rather than pulling the data to the processing.  However in anything but the most simple use-cases you often need to access related data and if you're doing process or network hops to do so, then you loose the performance.  After some playing about, I've worked out a way to get only the data in the current partition (and have shamelessly answered my own question)

Comment: I guess you used some internal API, don't you?